# issue in understanding how to create entity manager or if I can generate them in JAVA EE

Tags: java, jsf, jpa, jakarta-ee, entitymanager

I'm creating a JAVA EE project with JPA and JSF primefaces on a glassfish server.

---

Development environment is ECLIPSE IDE

Here is what I've done so far:

- I Created the database in SQLServer (3tables, not that complicated structure)
- I generated the entities from my table using JPA (eclipse offer this option...)

Here is what I want to do:

- Generate the entity managers (session beans) for my entities so I can manage and create records in my database
- finally I will create a UI using primefaces to display and edit and manage these records..

Question: Am I on the right path ? (conception level, or am I missing something out) + How to do my next step and that is generate the entity managers for my entities, Thanks in advance!

Comment: I usually just use to eclipse to generate the entities and DAO's

Comment: entity managers u create them by your self ? that's kinda complicated to do..., also do you generate DAO's using hibernate ?

Comment: When you generate everything, what exactly do you learn?

Comment: @Gimby there is reason for looking on how to generate these things... I'm working on other projects, too bad i don't think that i've time to struggle with the creation of each session beans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right path, but entity managers and session beans are not the same. You will use an `EntityManager` inside your session beans, like so:

```
@Stateless
public class MyService {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;
}
```

Make sure you have your `persistence.xml` file present. Further reading and examples can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/persistence-intro003.htm).

Example `persistence.xml` file that uses a container managed datasource located through JNDI at `jdbc/MyOrderDB`:

```
<persistence>
    <persistence-unit name="OrderManagement">
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/MyOrderDB</jta-data-source>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: understood, so I can't generate session beans, right ? i will just have to create them by my self

Comment: Eclipse does have some templates for creating the EJBs, but as far as the methods in them you'll have to implement them depending on what functionality you need.

Comment: Yes, I can see that know... it just popped out to my mind that JAVA EE is like JAVA... IDEs can create a skeleton for you with the basic functionalities such as what crud does. unfortunately this is not the case

Comment: CRUD has been abstracted in the `EntityManager`. For more complex queries I'd suggest looking at the `CriteriaQuery` API.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach looks simple and straight forward. Its alright.
For proceeding further, this article can help you.
http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1671224&seqNum=2

Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: it looks like a decent good example to understand how everything works to build an app.. I also noticed that he created the session bean and entity managers. So I think that confirm that I can't generate them. Thank you !